# Nested UITableView of variable height in UITableViewCell + UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a `UITableView` in which the cells contain an `ImageView` and a nested `UITableView`. The nested table can contain a variable number of cells and therefore has a variable height (and it isn't scrollable).

I am trying to set the parent cell height to be equal to the height of the image and the nested table view with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` but it is only extending as far as the image, probably because the table view starts with a height of 0 and is populated after it is created in the parent cell.

How can I make the parent table cells be the same height as their content? I have already set the constraints between the cell content view and the image/nested table.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue while trying to implement nested tableViews. I found two solutions to this problem.

1. Calculating the height of the innerTableView and setting the rowHeight of the outerTableView to it by executing the following in it's cellForRowAtIndexPath

rowHeight = cell.innerTableView.contentSize.height

return rowHeight in tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath and tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath

This worked for me to set the outerTableView's cellHeight depending on inner content.

2. Check this tutorial out. 
   http://vuta.info/dynamic-uitableviews-height-with-auto-layout-in-swift/

Comment: link is not working ... u may update the answer ...

Answer (score -1):

Done similar thing today. Here is what worked for me.

Neither need to set UITableViewAutomaticDimension nor setting tableView.rowHeight property.

First disable scrolling in inner table view.

```
innerTableView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

or if you designed it in storyboard, you can uncheck scrolling enabled property.

[scrolling disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brYFJ.png)

Assume for every cell:

- image height = 100
- inner table view's cell height = 30

Then calculate the cell's height is equal to image height plus nested table view's cells count multiplied by cell size  in tableView(tableView:heightForRowAt) e.g:

```
// constant
let imgHeight = 100
let innerCellHeight = 30

// inner cell count
let dataSource = dataSources[indexPath.row]
let innerCellsCount = dataSource.items.count


return CGFloat( imgHeight + ( innerCellsCount * innerCellHeight ) )
```

also implement tableView(tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAt) function so scrolling will be smoother e.g If inner table view might be contains no cells simply return image height.